# ggplot2 legend for stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I create a legend informing that the red cross is the mean?

```
ggplot(results, aes(x=factor, y=proportionPositive)) +
geom_boxplot() +
stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", colour = "red", shape=4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

1. Map an aesthetic to a shape, i.e. aes(shape="mean")
2. Create a manual shape scale, i.e. scale_shape_manual()

> ```
> # Create dummy data
> results <- data.frame(
>   factor=factor(rep(1:10, 100)), 
>   proportionPositive=rnorm(1000))
>
> # Plot results
> ggplot(results, aes(x=factor, y=proportionPositive)) +
>       geom_boxplot() +
>       stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", 
>               aes(shape="mean"), 
>               colour = "red",
>               geom="point") +
>       scale_shape_manual("", values=c("mean"="x"))
> ```

[image]

Comment: If you want to use pch symbolsl it's possible to use Unicode numbers. In order to do that, just replace the 'x' by an Unicode value: "\U" then Unicode value (e.g. `"\U22C4"`). See [Unicode table][1] 

[1]: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22c4/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

for me option "show.legend=TRUE" simply did work out:

```
ggplot(aes(x=stimulus, y=EPN, fill=strategy))+ 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, show.legend=TRUE, geom="bar", position="dodge", colour="black", linetype="solid", size=0.3)
```

Comment: This surprisingly works, but not without adding a scale call, e.g., as above `... +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("mean"="x"))`

Answer (score 0):

To make it appear like a default legend (borrowing from @Andrie code):

```
ggplot(results, aes(x=factor, y=proportionPositive)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", 
              aes(shape=""), # Leave empty
              colour = "red",
              geom="point") +
      scale_shape_manual("mean", values= "") # Will show mean on top of the line
```