# R: GGPLOT2: How do I add labels in a line graph in ggplot2 using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below code and the legend is all wrong.
The black line shows up purple and in the legend the color labels are wrong. for red it says black, etc.

```
ggplot(newdata,aes(x=immigrants.per.day,y=cc.percent),show.legend = TRUE) +
+       stat_summary(aes(y = cc.percent, color = "red"),fun = mean, geom = "line", label = c('CC'), show.legend = TRUE) + 
+       stat_summary(aes(y = cd.percent, color = "blue"),fun = mean, geom = "line", show.legend = TRUE) + 
+       stat_summary(aes(y = dc.percent, color = "green"),fun = mean, geom = "line", show.legend = TRUE) +
+       stat_summary(aes(y = dd.percent, color = "black"),fun = mean, geom = "line", show.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

i did follow links below but not able to solve my problem.

[How can I add the legend for a line made with stat_summary in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453178/how-can-i-add-the-legend-for-a-line-made-with-stat-summary-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Try `+ scale_color_manual(values = c(red = "red", black = "black", ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
ggplot(newdata,aes(x=immigrants.per.day,y=cc.percent),show.legend = TRUE) +
       stat_summary(aes(y = cc.percent, color = "a1"),fun = mean, geom = "line", label = c('CC'), show.legend = TRUE) + 
       stat_summary(aes(y = cd.percent, color = "a2"),fun = mean, geom = "line", show.legend = TRUE) + 
       stat_summary(aes(y = dc.percent, color = "a3"),fun = mean, geom = "line", show.legend = TRUE) +
       stat_summary(aes(y = dd.percent, color = "a4"),fun = mean, geom = "line", show.legend = TRUE)+
scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("a1", "a2", "a3","a4"),
                      values = c("red", "blue", "green","black"))
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked great!! Thanks

Comment: If that solved it please mark the checkmark for answered