# Add legend for a custom stat_summary fun.data

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

How can I add a legend for an object I have added to my plot with `stat_summary`?

Here is an example:

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
    geom_violin(trim=FALSE)
data_summary <- function(x) {
    m <- mean(x)
    ymin <- m-sd(x)
    ymax <- m+sd(x)
    return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
}
p + stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary)

### Code from http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-violin-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization
```

[image]

I want to add a descriptive legend which explains what the line and the dot in the center of each violin plot represents.

According to the RELATED topic below, I am under the impression that this can be achieved by defining `aes(shape="")` in `stat_summary` and then adding `scale_shape_manual("", values=c("?"))`. But I have not had any success.

RELATED. [ggplot2 legend for stat_summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178813/ggplot2-legend-for-stat-summary)

Comment: Your related link looks like a duplicate to me.  Maybe clarify in your question why this is different?  Is it because you want to add two elements to the legend and not just one?

Comment: This might be helpful if you want to have an even more descriptive legend https://owi.usgs.gov/blog/boxplots/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have the gist of how this works, mapping a constant to some aesthetic and then using `scale_*_manual()` to clean the legend up.

In `scale_shape_manual()` I think remove the legend name, and add a second box to the legend by changing the `limits`.  I used `c("Mean", "1 SD")` but these can be whatever you want.

The number of shapes needed is dictated by the number of legend boxes so I give two to `values`, using `NA` for the second since the second box in the legend should be a line with no point.

Finally, I use `override.aes()` in `guide_legend()` to remove the line from the first box.

```
p + stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary, aes(shape = "Mean")) +
     scale_shape_manual(name = NULL, 
                        limits = c("Mean", "1 SD"),
                        values = c(19, NA),
                        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(0, 1))))
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to merge those two objects (`Mean`, `1 SD`) into one as well so as to construct exactly the object that is in the center of the violin plots?

Comment: @paropunam That's actually even easier. Follow the approach in the link you mentioned.